# How to flatmap a nested Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have nested string like as shown below. I want to flat map them to produce unique rows in Spark

My dataframe has

```
A,B,"x,y,z",D
```

I want to convert it to produce output like

```
A,B,x,D
A,B,y,D
A,B,z,D
```

How can I do that.

Basically how can i do flat map and apply any function inside the Dataframe

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

**Spark 2.0+**

`Dataset.flatMap`:

```
val ds = df.as[(String, String, String, String)]
ds.flatMap { 
  case (x1, x2, x3, x4) => x3.split(",").map((x1, x2, _, x4))
}.toDF
```

**Spark 1.3+**.

Use `split` and `explode` [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

```
val df = Seq(("A", "B", "x,y,z", "D")).toDF("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")
df.withColumn("x3", explode(split($"x3", ",")))
```

**Spark 1.x**

`DataFrame.explode` (deprecated in Spark 2.x)

```
df.explode($"x3")(_.getAs[String](0).split(",").map(Tuple1(_)))
```

Comment: I gotta remember the `Dataset` option -- thanks for adding that.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Thanks. I should have close it as a duplicate but I marked wrong question by mistake so I decided to answer and add something new :)

Comment: @zero323 I checked the scala api docs for `explode` in `functions` and it doesn't show as deprecated. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Comment: @elghoto That link points to the doc for the utility function `explode`, whereas I believe that zero323 is referring to the DataFrame transformation `explode`, which has apparently been deprecated since 2.0.0: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset